# Can a multitasking app receive a notification when the device unlocks the screen even if the app is in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, multitasking

My app needs to perform a calculation every time the device unlocks. It's an app which the user launches intentionally and then enters background, similar like a pasteboard manager.

How can it receive a notification when the device unlocks while the app is in the background? Is this possible? The calculation is not heavy. It just reads and writes a value from/to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: You case refer UILocalNotification, following might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044092/uilocalnotification-in-sleep-mode-on-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075702/iphone-alarms-that-wake-up-the-device-from-sleep-with-sound

Comment: @RIP you cannot tell when the device screen unlocks through UILocalNotification

Comment: @Daniel - We can use applicationDidBecomeActive: and applicationWillResignActive: when application goes in foreground and background when device unlock or lock.

Comment: @RIP no, you cant, because the local notificaiton wont trigger that unless the user clicks on it, furthermore, the user can receive the notification while the device is unlocked so you can never say, YES the device has unlocked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current SDK and public API there is no way to tell when the user unlocks the screen, even if your app is in the background...

Comment: UILocalNotification can be used for this case.

Comment: how can you use a UILocalNotification to know whenthe screen unlocks?

Comment: Can you go into detail about UILocalNotification? How can it help in this case? Any code examples?

Comment: @MikhaloIvanokov You can't know when the screen is unlocked, even with UILocalNotifications.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - applicationDidBecomeActive: and applicationWillResignActive: methods can be used when screen is locked/unlocked.

Comment: But how could for example a background app like skype keep its connection alive when device is locked? How to perform operations when locked or unlocked, or in background?

Comment: @RIP no, you cant, because the local notificaiton wont trigger that unless the user clicks on it, furthermore, the user can receive the notification while the device is unlocked so you can never say, YES the device has unlocked..

Comment: @MikhaloIvanokov there a various multitasking background modes, one of them is VOIP, check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3 for more info

Comment: @Daniel - but we get informed when device unlocked, app will call becomeActive method and then we can schedule the things. Also following is mentioned in document ion - " Applications that run in the allowed period in the background may also present a local notification, scheduled or immediate, to inform the user of an incoming message, chat, or update. " Following is the link - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @RIP you are wrong, you cannot tell when the device is unlocked... and further more the UILOcalNOtification only activates the app if it is clicked..

Comment: @Daniel- as for as i know if app is running and device got locked, then when device is unlocked then applicationDidBecomeActive method is called, i won't have device right now, so i can't test. I will try doing this to test.

Comment: @RIP if your app is in the background and the device gets locked, when it unlocks applicationDidBecomeActive does not get called...why would it