# Is it possible to generate or receive a local notification when the device gets unlocked?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, multitasking, uilocalnotification

My app is running in the background and must know when the device has been unlocked, in order to resume some important operations. The user relys on it still working even after the app enters background or the device gets locked and unlocked again.

Someone suggested using UILocalNotification to notify the app but I don't see how? Also I want no dialogue to prompt the user with some question. App just has to perform a quick operation upon unlock.

Comment: why are you keep asking the same question ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a multitasking app receive a notification when the device unlocks the screen even if the app is in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301301/can-a-multitasking-app-receive-a-notification-when-the-device-unlocks-the-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
[UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification)

A bit more accurately, `applicationWillResignActive` gets called when the app moves to the background, not only due to screen lock.

Comment: I know that. I want to know how the app can perform a small calculation every time the device is unlocked. Even if the app is in the background and a different app is in focus.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Following methods will be used when device unlocks/lock -

1. When device locks - applicationWillResignActive:
2. When divide unlocks - applicationDidBecomeActive:

In these method we can use UILocalNotification to perform some task as per our need.